# ArcGIS Localization API

Tags: javascript, localization, frameworks, maps, arcgis

I'm dealing with a very annoying issue regarding arcGIS maps service localization.

According to their API I've added the following JS object:

dojoConfig = {
     locale: "fr",
     parseOnLoad: true
   };

and added the following item to the require array:
   "dojo/i18n!myApp/nls/jsapi"

When I've made this additions the maps aren't working anymore.

This is my full code:
**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.11/esri/css/esri.css">
<script src="http://js.arcgis.com/3.11/"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="mapDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
dojoConfig = {
  locale: "fr",
  parseOnLoad: true
};

var map;
    require([
      "esri/map",
      "dojo/i18n!myApp/nls/jsapi", 
      "dojo/domReady!"
    ], function(Map) {
      map = new Map("mapDiv", {
        center: [56.049, 38.485],
        zoom: 3,
        basemap: "streets"
      });
    });
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/viyevepehi/3/edit)

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have a file called myApp/nls/jsapi.js in your application, so `require` can't find it and can't run your function that initializes the map.

As [the documentation](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jshelp/localization.html) says:

> **After creating the resource bundle for the new locale**, load the resource module

You should read [the documentation for dojo/i18n](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/i18n.html). It makes more clear what you need to do.